# What is the exact meaning of "il n'y a pas à chipoter"?

Tags: sens, expressions

> **Il n'y a pas à chipoter**, la tomate ronde est belle et bien la reine des légumes farcis.

Given the core meaning "nibble" of the word "chipoter", does the expression mean "let's not mince words"? I assume "no doubt about it" doesn't quite cut it.

Here, this figurative expression is apparently intended as a joke, simultaneously alluding to the literal meaning of "chipoter" in the light of the "légumes"-oriented context.

Comment: By the way, the accord in "belle et bien" pulled me up short. Surely it is not grammatical?

Comment: Should be *bel et bien*

Comment: And *chipoter* now only means to argue in a petty way, the original meaning is lost.

Comment: @jlliagre So this must be a colloquial equivalent of the English expression "there's no arguing the fact that ...". I wonder what are the synonyms of "il n'y a pas à chipoter"?

Comment: You can say "Il n'y a pas à tergiverser", "Ne tournons pas autour du pot", "Allons droit au but".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> this figurative expression is apparently intended as a joke, simultaneously alluding to the literal meaning of "chipoter" in the light of the "légumes"-oriented context.

Je doute que quiconque voit une intention humoristique dans l'emploi de *chipoter* dans la phrase à cause du fait que la discussion porte sur de la nourriture.
Le mot est employé de façon tout à fait courante pour parler du fait de « marchander de façon mesquine » sans que l'on pense à une allusion à de la nourriture.

*Il n'y a pas à chipoter* ici veut dire que « ça ne sert à rien de discuter ». Celui qui dit ça montre que pour lui toute discussion est inutile. Il aurait aussi bien pu dire :

- Inutile de discuter.
- Pas la peine de discuter.

Visiblement tu connais déjà le sens figuré de *chipoter*, qui a des synonymes, ou quasi synonymes, mais qui sont certainement moins courants que « chipoter » (*ergoter, discuter de façon mesquine, barguigner, vétiller* (emploi vieilli, du moins en France), donc ce qu'il est peut-être plus intéressant de noter ici c'est que cet emploi du mot  est  plus ancien que son emploi pour dire « manger du bout des dents », qui, bien qu'encore employé de nos jours, l'est peut-être moins.

Le mot *chipoter* vient de *chipe*<sup>1</sup> (« chiffon ») avec le suffixe diminutif *-oter* (1306)

> Les sens figurés, « tourmentés, contrarier » et, avec l'idée liée au suffixe, « vétiller, discuter sur des riens » (1531) précèdent le sens propre de « manger par petits morceaux » (1704). Ces deux valeurs sont restées vivaces aujourd'hui. (*Dictionnaire historique en langue française*, 1992, sld Alain Rey)

<sup>1</sup>  <sub>D'origine germanique et qui a donné *chiffe, chiffon* en français, [*chip*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chip#Etymology) en anglais</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Using ***chipoter*** to mean "to nibble" is <s>almost</s> lost in current French. It is mostly used to mean "to complain, argue in a petty way about usually insignificant details", i.e. to **nitpick**, which is close to the original meaning (to annoy, torment).

[TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chipoter)

> *Étymol. et Hist. 1. 1458 chipotrer « tourmenter, contrarier » (Greban, Mist. de la pass., 22. 158 G. Paris, ds Gdf.); 2. 1561 « faire des difficultés, vétiller » (Calv., Comm. s. l'harm. évang., p. 125 ds Gdf. Compl. : chippoter sur chacun mot); 3. 1704 « manger par petits morceaux » (Trév.). Dér. de chipe*; suff. -oter*.*

A common synonym is *pinailler* although *il n'y a pas à pinailler* is rare. There is also *chicaner* but it is less common nowadays in France. It might still be used regionally and has a different meaning in Canadian French.

I might then translate that expression by:

> No question about it,…

As a side note, ***bel*** et bien is adverbial so shouldn't agree to *tomate*.

Comment: upvote for nitpicking!

Comment: @Laure Thanks, I wasn't aware it was still locally used that way. Answer updated.

Comment: A google search "chipoter + nourriture" shows it is far from local and it is widely used and understood.

Comment: @Laure, Tu chipotes… ;-) Pour être clair, je ne connais personne qui emploie «chipoter» pour «grignoter» (*to nibble*). En revanche, on peut bien sûr chipoter sur la nourriture, c'est à dire refuser de consommer certains plats ou se plaindre et les manger à contre-cœur.

Comment: @Laure Relis la question attentivement ainsi que l'entrée « chipoter » dans le TLFi, premier sens A.

Comment: OED : "Nibble To take little bites of (a thing), to bite away little by little." En français c'est grignoter.

Comment: « Manger du bout des dents, lentement et sans appétit. » (TLF, je vois pas où il est dit que ça veuille dire grignoter). *Grignoter* c'est simplement mordiller / manger du bout des dents sans connotation affective.. Pour lui donner le sens de *chipoter *on lui rajoute « sans fin / sans appétit ». Et chipoter pour dire manger sans appétit est encore compris et employé en français pour parler de la nourriture dans le sens de manger par petits morceaux sans appétit.  De plus le sens original de *chipoter* est celui de « discuter sur des riens ».

Comment: @Laure Ce n'est plus du chipotage mais de la mauvaise foi. TLFi: ***Grignoter**: Manger quelque chose en le croquant, en le rongeant petit à petit, du bout des dents. … 2. P. ext.
a) Manger très peu, sans appétit.* Dictionnaire de l'ancienne langue française, Godefroy: ***Chipotrer**: v.a. **Tourmenter**. Passez avant, pute meignie, allez le moy ça chipotrer. Lyonnais et Suisse romande: chipoter, contrarier*

Comment: Je retourne la remarque "de mauvaise foi" en ajoutant les exemples "oubliés" du TLF. «  C'était pourquoi M. de Kermaheuc grignotait sans faim,  » « ... grignotait, ne mangeait guère,.. ” grignoter n'est pas employer tout seul. Par contre on est bien d'accord que chipoter veut dire tourmenter, je n'ai jamais dit le contraire, c'est même le sens premier du mot.

Answer (score -1):

Means arguing for no valid reason.

I'm french.

Comment: Bienvenue sur French Language. Avant de répondre il vaut toujours mieux consulter un dictionnaire. Chipoter ne veut pas dire discuter sans bonne raison mais discuter, faire des difficultés sur des broutilles, « Ergoter, discuter sur de menues dépenses, marchander longuement et avec mesquinerie.  » (TLF) .